# Inbox messages for deleted question

Tags: bug, ios-app

Comments for deleted question was not deleted from inbox section. I think they should be also deleted.

- App Version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 9.3.5 (Build 13G36)

Comment: @ShadowWizard my situation is about question deleted by OP, not only for viewed notifications

Comment: Same thing as far as I can tell. No matter what cause the comment to be deleted, the notification is removed in the site, but not  in the app.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I see notification in web (but only last of 2) for deleted question. But in app I see both of them. It seems problem is more complicated